# Python: "could not convert string to float" error when fitting np arrays into model

Tags: python, type-conversion, numpy-ndarray, dtype

I am trying to do a Fake News Classification model, so as part of the pre processing, I did stopword removal, stemming and lemmatization. Afterwards I used Doc2Vec to convert the text into vectors.
x and y are the vectorized text and title columns of the FER2013 dataset, and looks something like this:

```
array(['[-0.78902    -1.3584563  -1.2094668   1.2671869  -0.505878   -0.46793452 -0.05335827 -0.3953245   0.64238095  0.29936427  0.64882624 -0.9903825 -0.16372935 -0.5240088  -0.8061704   0.94803816  0.49816552  1.0211618 -0.3891333  -0.53825814]',
   '[ 1.3473806  -2.2537904  -0.01150447  1.0409713  -0.17815335 -0.92815816  0.01454325 -1.78424    -1.2680324   0.39823842 -0.3313817  -0.7288629 -2.3424263   0.50622666 -0.1096359   0.6213235  -0.18285985  1.0153825  0.12197232 -0.31061244]',
   '[-0.21220133 -0.94656384 -0.31035122 -0.20017953 -0.04308065 -0.2723616  0.13090962 -0.51174223 -0.63989     0.9296897  -1.516201    0.90435594  0.19001946 -0.60641354  1.2848449  -0.9736119   0.05583194 -0.55788654 -1.2701703   1.361641  ]',
   ...,
   '[ 0.07217433 -0.01937062 -0.6813549   0.9267837   0.8567494   0.11055075 -0.49166957  0.05391011 -0.4867952   0.68353873 -0.34195983  0.11552304  0.07995445 -0.68140924  0.14169812  0.05574211  0.85227823  0.28077438  0.08299595 -0.93785906]',
   '[-0.03407184  1.0156128  -0.3216298   0.38381922  0.41431156 -0.22601238 -0.45248717 -0.918599   -0.16802132  0.1707096  -0.9931418  -0.62819743 -0.22415633 -2.451051   -0.26168516 -0.04228298  0.71497554 -0.27817437 -1.0023195  -0.43352002]',
   '[-0.60217994  0.1949403   0.29088852 -0.5941371   0.5181151  -0.789163  0.887305   -1.6515299  -0.8250909   0.11755247  0.08880343 -0.23532224  0.52777374  0.31153452 -0.39013034 -0.08209435  1.7401134   1.4870292 -0.18821365  1.1624134 ]'],
  dtype=object)
```

This is the code I'm using for the train-test split and fit:

```
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
print(model.score(xtest, ytest))
```

But here, there was the problem of line breaks in the vector elements. So, as a result, when I converted it into np arrays to fit the model, a "\n" character was generated at the end.
I replaced "\n" with empty value to solve this but the same error persists.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[ 0.3060216   0.04662842  0.44954425  1.4223956   1.3165258   0.7194798  1.2665545  -0.4921699  -0.01131658  0.02519435 -0.6978444  -1.2564504 -0.6709047   0.02319291  0.05263066 -0.1006538   1.3066514  -0.9096088  0.3219977   0.31393617]'
```

When I check the dtype of these arrays it shows it as object even though in the error, it is specified as string.

Comment: x or y is a string i think

Comment: But when I check dtype shouldn't it return string then?

Comment: what's your x and your y? could you add those to the question? (if they aren' very long)

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the question

Comment: so efectively your array is a list of strings..

Comment: I see, could you suggest the best way to convert it to an array?

Comment: @UlisesBussi I just tried converting x to array using this code "x = list(map(int, x))" but that returns this error : "invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

Comment: hi there the problem are other characters but numbers, and your numbers are floats be carefull, from where you got that string? maybe it's an easy way to get that in float directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove **machine learning** from tags it is a **python** error !

The error is **clear** you are trying to transform a String to float and that String contains **'['** char and contains **blank spaces** ... it can't be transformed
you need to clean that String :

```
def check_float(element) :
    try:
        float(element)
        return(True)
    except ValueError : 
        return False

new_List_floats=[]
for st in that_array : 
    List_of_string = st.split(" ")
    for element in List_of_string :
        el = element.split(" ")[0]
        el =element.split("]")[0]
        el = element.split("[")[0]
        if check_float(el) :
            new_List_floats +=[float(el)]
```

Now you can use the new List to **complete your process**  just be careful to the shape of your array and make some changes in the code if needed .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked in cleaning the array. However, with regard to your caution on the shape of the resulting array, could you suggest what changes are to be made in the code? Because when I applied this code to x and y, the resulting arrays had different shapes @sabrimahmoud

Comment: @mxverik let it be an exercice for you just try to reshape the resulting list to what ever shape you need later